# Sphinx, reStructuredText show/hide code snippets

Tags: code-snippets, show-hide, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I've been documenting a software package using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/rest.html) and [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).

Within my documents, there are some long code snippets. I want to be able to have them hidden as default, with a little "Show/Hide" button that would expand them ([Example](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/showhide-content/)).

Is there a standard way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to create a custom Sphinx theme in which you tell certain html elements to have this functionality.  A little JQuery would go a long way here.

If, however you want to be able to specify this in your reStructuredText markup, you would need to either

- get such a thing included in Sphinx itself or
- implement it in a Sphinx/docutils extension...and then create a Sphinx theme which knew about this functionality.

This would be a bit more work, but would give you more flexibility.

Comment: Can you share how and what you've develop for `show/hide` facility on sphinx documentation?

Answer (score 51):

You don't need a custom theme. Use the built-in directive `container` that allows you to add custom css-classes to blocks and override the existsting theme to add some javascript to add the show/hide-functionality.

This is `_templates/page.html`:

```
{% extends "!page.html" %}

{% block footer %}
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggle > *").hide();
        $(".toggle .header").show();
        $(".toggle .header").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().children().not(".header").toggle(400);
            $(this).parent().children(".header").toggleClass("open");
        })
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is `_static/custom.css`:

```
.toggle .header {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.toggle .header:after {
    content: " ▶";
}

.toggle .header.open:after {
    content: " ▼";
}
```

This is added to `conf.py`:

```py
def setup(app):
    app.add_css_file('custom.css')
```

Now you can show/hide a block of code.

```
.. container:: toggle

    .. container:: header

        **Show/Hide Code**

    .. code-block:: xml
       :linenos:

       from plone import api
       ...
```

I use something very similar for exercises here: https://training.plone.org/5/mastering-plone/about_mastering.html#exercises

Comment: Beautiful! Would be nice if the toggle solutions showed up as clickable links in vimperator/cvim/pentadactyl though.

Comment: I think that using ▶ and ▼ makes it more intuitive to use. (See [Confluence as an example](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/expand-macro-223222352.html)). Get the unicode values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11537979/1398841).

Comment: This snippet `{% set css_files = css_files + ["_static/custom.css"] %}` results in a Sphinx warning: `RemovedinSphinx20Warning: builder.css_files is deprecated. Please use app.add_stylesheet() instead`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980230/1398841) for a work around.

Comment: Would you mind posting the detailed instructions for the example from your plone course, which is using an admonition?

Comment: How to get the arrow in the same line as the header?

Comment: @dexteritas to keep the arrow on the same line you can simply set  ``.toggle .header {display: inline;}`` in css file

Comment: @matusko Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything for me either. The arrow is still in the next line.

Comment: Change `.toggle .header:after` to `.toggle .header p:after` and `.toggle .header.open:after` to `.toggle .header.open p:after` to avoid this issue @dexteritas

Answer (score 26):

You can use the built-in HTML collapsible [`details`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp) tag by wrapping the code in two raw HTML directives

```
.. raw:: html

   <details>
   <summary><a>big code</a></summary>

.. code-block:: python

   lots_of_code = "this text block"

.. raw:: html

   </details>
```

Produces:

```html
<details>
<summary><a>big code</a></summary>
<pre>lots_of_code = "this text block"</pre>
</details>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a very simplistic extension providing exactly that feature: https://github.com/scopatz/hiddencode

It works rather well for me.

Answer (score 5):

The cloud sphinx theme has custom directive `html-toggle` that provides toggleable sections. To quote from their [web page](https://cloud-sptheme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud_theme.html#features):

> You can mark sections with `.. rst-class:: html-toggle`, which will make the section default to being collapsed under html, with a “show section” toggle link to the right of the title.

[Here](https://cloud-sptheme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud_theme_test.html#toggleable-section) is a link to their test demonstration page.

Answer (score 3):

[**sphinx-togglebutton**](https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-togglebutton)

Looks like a new sphinx extension has been made to do just this since this question has been answered.

---

Run: `pip install sphinx-togglebutton`

Add to `conf.py`

```
extensions = [
...
'sphinx_togglebutton'
...
]
```

In rst source file:

```
.. admonition:: Show/Hide
  :class: dropdown

  hidden message
```

Answer (score 2):

since none of the above methods seem to work for me, here's how I solved it in the end:

1. create a file `substitutions.rst` in your source-directory with the following content:

   ```
   .. |toggleStart| raw:: html

      <details>
      <summary><a> the title of the collapse-block </a></summary>

   .. |toggleEnd| raw:: html

      </details>
      <br/>
   ```
2. add the following line at the beginning of every file you want to use add collapsible blocks

   ```
   ..include:: substitutions.rst
   ```
3. now, to make a part of the code collapsible simply use:

   ```
   |toggleStart|

   the text you want to collapse
   ..code-block:: python 
       x=1

   |toggleEnd|
   ```

Comment: This is basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394068/407651

Comment: @mzjn yes It is... but I thought using substitutions makes it a bit more compact and readable (especially if you have a lot of collapsible segments with the same title-text)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the dropdown directive in the [sphinx-design](https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/furo-theme/dropdowns.html) extension. From the docs:

1. Install sphinx-design

```bash
pip install sphinx-design
```

2. Add the extension to `conf.py` in the `extensions` list

```
extensions = ["sphinx_design"]
```

3. Use the `dropdown` directive in your rst file:

```
.. dropdown::

    Dropdown content
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.20 (2023-05-09), the Docutils HTML5 writer supports [details disclosure elements](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/test/functional/expected/standalone_rst_html5.html#details-disclosure-elements).
For the source rST, see
https://docutils.sourceforge.io/test/functional/input/data/html5-features.txt