# How to show and hide code in sphinx doc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want the same functionality mention in [Sphinx, reStructuredText show/hide code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454577/sphinx-restructuredtext-show-hide-code-snippets). But there is no code shared on that post.

Comment: So you are basically asking us to implement this for you?  This isn't just a few lines of code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I didn't mean the development & I thought it could be sphinx feature, if its already exists or an extension provided by sphinx or 3rd party extension then somebody can share...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### SQLAlchemy docs

The SQLAlchemy documentation uses a special extension (https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/zzzeeksphinx/).

The documentation source contains markup with custom options and tokens, like in this example:

```
.. sourcecode:: python+sql
 
    {sql}>>> engine.execute("select 1").scalar()
    select 1
    ()
    {stop}1
```

This is processed by a special Pygments [lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment) (`PythonWithSQLLexer`) and Pygments [formatter](http://pygments.org/docs/formatterdevelopment) (`PopupSQLFormatter`) in order to generate a "popup" `<div>` with the code snippet and the link that shows/hides it. The source code is in [sqlformatter.py](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/zzzeeksphinx/src/master/zzzeeksphinx/sqlformatter.py).

The show/hide toggling is handled by jQuery magic in [init.js](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/zzzeeksphinx/src/master/zzzeeksphinx/themes/zzzeeksphinx/static/init.js).

The [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org) templating system is used to generate the HTML pages (the default templating system in Sphinx is Jinja). This is configured by subclassing `TemplateBridge` in [mako.py](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/zzzeeksphinx/src/master/zzzeeksphinx/mako.py).

In the template file [layout.mako](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/zzzeeksphinx/src/master/zzzeeksphinx/themes/zzzeeksphinx/layout.mako), the paths to CSS and JavaScript files (including init.js) are specified. For more on Sphinx templating, see http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html.

#### Python docs

Many code examples in the Python documentation feature a "button" that toggles display of interactive prompts (`>>>`, `...`) and output in doctest-style code snippets. With prompts and output out of the way, the code can be more easily copied and pasted. Here are several examples: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime.

The feature is implemented in [copybutton.js](http://docs.python.org/_static/copybutton.js).

Comment: @shahjapan: What do you mean by integrate?

Comment: I mean where do I place this init.js ?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want... In the SQLAlchemy docs, init.js is in the `_static` dir of the Sphinx build. View the source of [this page](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/). See also the Mako template file [layout.mako](https://bitbucket.org/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/src/tip/doc/build/templates/layout.mako).