# Show/hide part of text (question/answer) in sphinx file

Tags: python-sphinx

I was wondering if there is a method to add a directive to a sphinx document with a hidden section that can be opened with a click.

Basically something like you can find https://realpython.com/pandas-python-explore-dataset/ (search for Show/Hide):

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454577/407651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example from the [Mastering Plone Training documentation](https://training.plone.org/5/mastering-plone/dexterity.html#exercise-1).

And here's the [source code](https://github.com/plone/training/blame/master/mastering-plone/dexterity.rst#L243).

```
..  admonition:: Solution
    :class: toggle
    * Go to the dexterity-controlpanel (http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@dexterity-types)
    * Click on *Page* (http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/dexterity-types/Document)
    * Select the tab *Behaviors* (http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/dexterity-types/Document/@@behaviors)
    * Check the box next to *Lead Image* and save.
```

The [commit history](https://github.com/plone/training/commit/c67f675b7b569c12b7ed6df731d7505577bdbab9) shows that a custom JavaScript and style were added to the theme.

### _static/custom.css

```
.toggle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e7f2fa;
}

.toggle .admonition-title {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.toggle .admonition-title:after {
    content: " ▼";
}

.toggle .admonition-title.open:after {
    content: " ▲";
}
```

### _templates/page.html

```
{% set css_files = css_files + ["_static/custom.css"] %}

{%- block extrahead %}
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //
        //
        $(".toggle > *").hide();
        $(".toggle .admonition-title").show();
        $(".toggle .admonition-title").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().children().not(".admonition-title").toggle(400);
            $(this).parent().children(".admonition-title").toggleClass("open");
        })
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for (and bonus that I'm also using rtd theme!). Super thanks!