# Export html in sphinx without custom admonitions

Tags: python-sphinx

Following my other question [Show/hide part of text (question/answer) in sphinx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59679797/show-hide-part-of-text-question-answer-in-sphinx-file?noredirect=1#comment105517561_59679797) what I would like to do is to export an `html` (or whatever format) **without** this tag (e.g. an `html` without all the `admonition` directives.

I read the `.. only::` directive but it seems that you I can exclude an entire page from an `html` and let it in the `latex` for example.

Comment: Did you actually try this? Did you try to indent content under the `only` directive? You can nest directives by indenting them under one another.

Comment: Didn't know that I can nest directives. Thanks! If you put you comment as a reply I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest directives by indenting them under one another.

```
.. only:: html

    ..  admonition:: Solution
        :class: toggle

        * Go to the dexterity-controlpanel (http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@dexterity-types)
        * Click on *Page* (http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/dexterity-types/Document)
        * Select the tab *Behaviors* (http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/dexterity-types/Document/@@behaviors)
        * Check the box next to *Lead Image* and save.
```