# Collapsible section on restructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

I try to add a collapsible section on a restructuredText file, but I fail to find some support material. For markdown text, it is straight-forward: https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab

Best regards.

Comment: Which tools are you using to render the rst? Some have extensions for this (such as Sphinx has sphinx-design) but it's not a native rst feature

Comment: If you are using Sphinx, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454577/407651

Answer (score 1):

Since release 0.18 (2021-10-26), Docutils' HTML5 writer natively supports [details disclosure elements](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/test/functional/expected/standalone_rst_html5.html#details-disclosure-elements). The example in the above link is generated from:

```
.. class:: details

A summary
  with details only visible after user interaction.

.. class:: details open

Another summary
  with open details because the source list has the additional class
  value "open".
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [Sphinx Design extension](https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io), which offers [dropdown](https://sphinx-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dropdowns.html) doing what you are asking for.